# Point in table of contents with titletoc and indents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

It would be nice if someone can teach me how to get a point behind the section numbers in the table of contents. I use the package titletoc.

Besides I have two questions concerning the indents. How could I get one at the very first line after a section title? And how could I (globally) define a space between two paragraphs (without losing the indent)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]{\large}{\contentslabel{1.5em}}{\hspace*{-1.5em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vspace*{0.3em}]
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\normalfont\large\textsc{Contents}}
\tableofcontents
\section{The first section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
\section{The second section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are: you have to use the optional argument of \contentslabel. Note you don't need to re-dsefine  `\contentsname`.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[indentafter]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[1.5em]{\large}{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.5em}}{\hspace*{-1.5em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\vspace*{0.3em}]

\begin{document}

    {\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\large\scshape}\tableofcontents}

\section{The first section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\section{The second section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You also have an idea about my "indent" problems?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that (Freudian slip? I think it's a typographical heresy). It's just an option in  `titlesec`, see my updated answer. As to the spacing between paragraphs, set  `\parskip` to some small (rubber) length. But you shouldn't use both paragraph indentation and paragraph spacing without very serious reasons.

Comment: Alright, then I won't use `\parskip`. Do you know how I could get the wort 'Contens' centered? With `\centering` from my MWE it doesn't work and with `\begin{center}...\end{center}` there is a huge space to the first entry of the Toc.

Comment: @user372565:  you can use the `{\titleformat*{\section}{...}}` command (between braces, to make it local. See my updated answer. However if you also have a bibliography or an index, and want their titles to be centred, you'd better declare `\titleformat {name=\section, numberless}{\large\scshape\filcenter}{}{0pt} {}` in the preamble.